# MongoDB search $in _id php

Tags: php, mongodb

Usually when I search for one related ID I do it like this:

```
$thisSearch = $collection->find(array(
    'relatedMongoID' => new MongoId($mongoIDfromSomewhereElse)
));
```

How would I do it if I wanted to do something like this:

```
$mongoIdArray = array($mongoIDfromSomewhereElseOne, $mongoIDfromSomewhereElseTwo, $mongoIDfromSomewhereElseThree);
$thisSearch = $collection->find(array(
        'relatedMongoID' => array( '$in' => new MongoId(mongoIdArray)
    )));
```

I've tried it with and without the  new MongoId(), i've even tried this with no luck.

```
foreach($mongoIdArray as $seprateIds){

$newMongoString .= new MongoId($seprateIds).', ';

}
$mongoIdArray = explode(',', $newMongoString).'0';
```

how do I search '$in' "_id" when you need to have the new MongoID() ran on each _id?

Answer (score 8):

Hmm your rtying to do it the SQL way:

```
foreach($mongoIdArray as $seprateIds){

$newMongoString .= new MongoId($seprateIds).', ';

}
$mongoIdArray = explode(',', $newMongoString).'0';
```

Instead try:

```
$_ids = array();
foreach($mongoIdArray as $seprateIds){
    $_ids[] = $serprateIds instanceof MongoId ? $seprateIds : new MongoId($seprateIds);
}
$thisSearch = $collection->find(array(
    'relatedMongoID' => array( '$in' => $_ids)
));
```

That should produce a list of `ObjectId`s that can be used to search that field - `relatedMongoID`.

### This is what I am doing

Basically, as shown in the documentation ( https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/ ) the `$in` operator for MongoDB in fact takes an array so you need to replicate this structure in PHP since the PHP driver is a 1-1 with the documentation on most fronts (except in some areas where you need to use an additional object, for example: `MongoRegex`)

Now, all `_id`s in MongoDB are in fact `ObjectId`s (unless you changed your structure) so what you need to do to complete this query is make an array of `ObjectId`s. The `ObjectId` in PHP is `MongoId` ( http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php )

So you need to make an array of `MongoId`s.

First, I walk through the array (could be done with `array_walk`) changing the values of each array element to a `MongoId` with the old value encapsulated in that object:

```
foreach($mongoIdArray as $seprateIds){
    $_ids[] = $serprateIds instanceof MongoId ? $seprateIds : new MongoId($seprateIds);
}
```

I use a ternary operator here to see if the value is already a `MongoId` encapsulated value, and if not encapsulate it.

Then I add this new array to the query object to form the `$in` query array as shown in the main MongoDB documentation:

```
$thisSearch = $collection->find(array(
    'relatedMongoID' => array( '$in' => $_ids)
));
```

So now when the query is sent to the server it forms a structure similar to:

```
{relatedMongoId: {$in: [ObjectId(''), ObjectId('')]}}
```

Which will return results.

Comment: what's happening here , can you describe a little ?

Answer (score 1):

Well... I came across the same issue and the solution might not be relevant anymore since the API might have changed. I solved this one with:

```
$ids = [
  new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId('5ae0cc7bf3dd2b8bad1f71e2'),
  new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId('5ae0cc7cf3dd2b8bae5aaf33'), 
];
$collection->find([
  '_id' => ['$in' => $_ids],
]);
```

Comment: You can use - new \MongoId().
$ids = [
  new \MongoId('5ae0cc7bf3dd2b8bad1f71e2'),
  new \MongoId('5ae0cc7cf3dd2b8bae5aaf33'), 
];
$collection->find([
  '_id' => ['$in' => $_ids],
]);